# Saving content from unresponsive exe

Tags: windows, data-recovery, process, dump

> Duplicate: [How do I recover a form in Firefox *without* installing a plugin?](https://superuser.com/q/236390/193661)

I have a `notepad.exe` process running that is unresponsive. I would like to save the contents. Can I somehow dump the process' current state and copy my text content from it?

Recover *text* data (non text binary would be a different solution) from hanging unresponsive process memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since taken a brief look at process dumps and found this problem to be very easy to solve, at least for `notepad`.

1. Create dump file for the process (you can use Task Manager)
2. Download the SysInternals tool, [strings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx)
3. Use `strings.exe [input file path] > [output file path]` in command line
4. There will be a bunch of other nonsense text in there as well and the file will be a few megabytes so you'll have to search for your text but it will be in there.
5. Don't use `notepad`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  If the program is completely unresponsive, then you will have to kill the process.

If you think about it, if it were easy to recover data from an unresponsive program, operating systems would have such functionality built in.

Comment: I suspect the main reason operating systems don't have this functionality is that the application would immediately become unresponsive again once you restore its state. That doesn't necessarily mean the document is unsalvageable.

Comment: The short answer is yes, but it's hard to do.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. Consider removing it.

Answer (score 1):

A long answer is that *in principle* you could save the whole process (including the open file) to a file, and by use of forensic tools (and a detailed knowledge of how it represents data in memory) piece together what the program was doing. Only that is is probably much faster to just write the d*mn text again. I believe [this](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Memory_Imaging) will give you a taste of what is available.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. Consider removing it.