# Configure Firefox to remember form changes when accidentally leaving a HTTPS page?

Tags: firefox, forms, data-loss-prevention

On some webpages, changed form content gets lost when the user (accidentally) leaves and goes back to the page (*before* submitting the form).

**Example scenario:** Bob edits a wiki page in Firefox. He changes existing content of the textarea and adds many new paragraphs. While typing, he accidentally presses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>. Whoops, now he is on the previous page. He clicks Firefox' "Next page" button to get back to the edit page. But, oh no, all his changes are gone.

As far as I tested, Firefox' default behaviour for forms on **HTTP** pages is fine: it keeps the changed content. But the same form on a **HTTPS** page "forgets" all unsaved changes. (assuming the webmaster didn't implement anything special)

Because it works for HTTP but doesn't work for HTTPS, it seems to be the responsibilty of the browser. I assume they deactivated it for security reasons. Is that correct?

Can this behaviour be disabled (in `about:config`)? Is it possible that Firefox remembers unsaved changes on HTTPS pages in the same way it does on HTTP pages?

I'm not talking about permanently *saving* the content with the help of a Firefox extension; it's not necessary to save form changes to be able to retrieve them anytime. I want to prevent content loss only for the situation when the user is navigating accidentally away and then going back **immediately** after (< 30 seconds).

---

### Related

If you *submitted* the form and something went wrong, see:

- [Does Firefox cache submitted form content anywhere I can recover?](https://superuser.com/q/512669/151741)
- [How do I recover a form in Firefox *without* installing a plugin?](https://superuser.com/q/236390/151741) (including a [nice way](https://superuser.com/a/236400/151741) to save and search through the memory of Firefox)
- [How to recover form information for a webpage in Firefox](https://superuser.com/q/183554/151741)

If you want to *save* all your form changes, see:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/

If you want to prevent this problem for visitors of your website:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/14420624/1591669 (*Onur YILDIRIM* gave a nice [overview of possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421723/1591669))

Answer (score 0):

Two Firefox extensions will accomplish what you desire.  One is called "Lazarus: Form Recovery" and the other is called "Textarea Cache".

Lazarus: Form Recovery is available here: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/

and Textarea Cache is available here: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/